# Reduce recursion in Javascript, Fusion Tables API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, google-fusion-tables

The values in the x-axis keep on recurring and I want only three values to appear: Rural, Peri Urban and Urban. Below is my Javascript code showing the `drawChar`t function used to visualize the chart. What could be the problem?

```
     function drawVisualization(County) {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: "visualization",
      dataSourceUrl: "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
      query: "SELECT Environment,'BoyPupils','GirlPupils' " +
          "FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s" +
          "WHERE Environment IN ('Rural','Urban'.'Peri Urban')",
      chartType: "ColumnChart",
      options: {
        title: County,
        height: 750,
        width: 1100
      }
    });
  }
```

[image: I want only three values to appear unlike in the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause for `Environment` and must  use `SUM` for the other columns

```
"SELECT Environment, \
          SUM('BoyPupils') as BoyPupils, \
          SUM('GirlPupils') as GirlPupils \
       FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s \
       GROUP BY Environment"
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L6Yqp/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L6Yqp/)